# UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum crash

Tags: ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller

I've a UIImagePickerController in video mode; after I finish recording video and I tap on "Use" button to accept the video I use this method `-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` and inside it i want save the video in camera roll and retrieve the first frame from the video to show it in UIImageView. The code that I use is the following:

```
    NSString *tempFilePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempFilePath];
            
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    imageView.image = [moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:0.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

The problem is that if I add the method `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum` the app crash.

```
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(tempFilePath, self,  @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

where `tmpFilePath` is the same that I used above.

Instead if I use only one of this operation (UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum or retrieve frame) all work fine !

The console report this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:]: method signature argument cannot be nil'

Any ideas ? Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your class, do you implement the following method?

```
- (void)video:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {
```

Comment: Ops... i forgot it. I'll try whit it.